# Understanding Keras Regularization

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am looking at implementing regularization to my model to improve validation accuracy. I came across keras's documentation as follows:

```
layer = layers.Dense(
    units=64,
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4),
    bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4),
    activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-5)
)
```

I would like to understand the difference between kernel, bias, and activity regularization and when I should use one or the other.

Also, I'd like to understand which values I should look at choosing to start off with and how best to tweak those values to improve validation accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Ossz,
There is a good description of regularization differences [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/383310/what-is-the-difference-between-kernel-bias-and-activity-regulizers-and-when-t).
You may want to use Tensorboard to see if your bias or weights get out of control or whether your activation function saturates; then apply relevant regularization. If this is not the case - default values (None) should give you decent results.